# Import npm module installed directly from github

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, github, npm

There is an [npm package](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) that I want to use in my Meteor app. It was
missing some features so I forked the repo and applied the patch myself.
I installed the forked package using:

`meteor npm install --save https://github.com/suheb/react-slick.git`

Now when I try to use the package using `import Slider from 'react-slick'`, I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-slick' install.js:101`

How can I use this package installed directly from github?

PS: I have asked the original owner to update the package on npm registry but I'm not sure long it'll take.

Comment: you can use git submodules https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Do you tried with `npm install https://github.com/suheb/react-slick` ?

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo Didn't work.

Comment: It may be that the npm package is just published from `dist/` or something.

Answer (score 0):

The package you want to install needs to be compiled by Babel before you can use it. GitHub repo contains only source code, not compiled JS. As @noah suggested, what is published to the NPM registry is compiled code (the result of running `prepublish` script defined in `package.json`).

Currently you are not able to install this kind of packages directly from a Git repository - the issue in NPM command line client that prevents it is tracked here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055

Please consider using this helper script (authored by me): https://github.com/lzrski/npm-git-install/